Inconsistency between theory relating refractive index and permittivity
It can be deduced from Maxwell's equations that the refractive index of a substance is equal to the root of its permittivity.
$$n=\sqrt{ε}$$
Furthermore, many studies show that a greater concentration of sugar causes the permitivitty of a water-sugar solution to decrease. In turn this means (according to what already has been said) that the refractive index should decrease.
Sources:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Measured-Dielectric-Constant-vs-Percentage-of-sugar-in-water-for-frequency-140GHz_fig5_272495010
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1465/1/012002/pdf#:~:text=It%20is%20known%20that%20permittivity,in%20water%20can%20be%20measured.&text=2.1.
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Real-part-relative-permittivity-as-a-function-of-sugar-weight-concentration-for_fig4_340484266
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Dielectric-constant-vs-concentration-of-glucose-solutions_fig4_11523946

Nevertheless, many other studies show that a greater sugar concentration of sugar means a greater refractive index.
Sources:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/shows-the-refractive-index-versus-concentrations-of-sugar-solution-using-Red-Diode-He-Ne_fig2_326377418
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-dependence-of-refractive-index-of-glucose-solution-vs-the-concentration-of-glucose-in_fig4_267944446
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-correlation-between-the-sugar-concentration-and-refractive-index_fig3_45817651
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/refractive-index-as-a-function-of-the-concentration-of-a-sugar-solution.920580/

How can this inconsistency be explained?

Of course! I have added the links to these sources in the question

I don't have a complete answer but permittivity is strongly influenced by resonances of the molecules or atoms involved. You will have very different resonances excited at 1-2 GHz compared to 500-1000 THz. There is some discussion of the effects involved for 1-2 GHz starting at the end of pg 64 in your first referenced paper, saying they involve the rotational motion of the  "relatively large" sugar molecule. It appears this motion can't be excited at optical frequencies --- leading to the much lower permittivity (1.33 compared to 20-80) in the optical measurement.

Look into dispersion. n (and hence $\epsilon$) depend on the frequency (or wavelength). Its not a constant.


It can be deduced from Maxwell's equations that the refractive index of a substance is equal to the root of its permittivity.
$n=\sqrt{\epsilon}$
Furthermore, many studies show that a greater concentration of sugar causes the >permitivitty of a water-sugar solution to decrease.
How can this inconsistency be explained?

Measurements for some of the sources are at different frequencies, and the correct definition here would be:
$n({\omega})=\sqrt{\epsilon{(\omega})}$
For optical frequencies (second example, at least the graph), you have the absorption of hydrogen bonds for a few wavelengths:

And here for the more general spectrum of absorption in water:

So here the problem is not inconsistency in the measurement. Rather, the situation is that the refractive index is not really a constant value that exclusively depends on the concentration of a specific material, as there is no precise correlation between density and "optical density" or refractive index.
It may be possible to explain for the RF frequencies that the decrease of the dielectric function for increased concentration due to reduced electron mobility from the increased organic species in the mixture, but I am not an expert in dielectric measurement for RF. In the optical regime (the laser measurements shown later) it is possible that the additional organic components are actually absorbing in that region causing an increased absorption in the media leading to increased refractive index (but that is just speculation, the papers should have more information of the standing theory of why this is happening).
